# working in FILE expected ')' before string constant

Tags: c

This code extract is from my final project in C course iam taking.
This is the first time for me using FILE and fopens can someone help me solve this problem and lead me to be able to save users data in my program so help me solve it

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//main function
int main(){
    system("cls"); //Clears screen
    mainmenu();
}
//date structure
struct date{
    int month,day,year;};
//main structure
struct {char name[50];
    char adress[60];
    char nationality[20];
    char acctype[23];
    double phone;
    int acc_no;
    double deposit;
    double age;
    struct date dob; //struct inside a struct for day of birth
    struct date newa;//struct in date struct for new account
    }add,check;

//new account function
void newacc(){

   FILE *records;
    records = fopen("records.dat","a+");

    system("cls");
    printf("Create an account Number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&check.acc_no);
     if(check.acc_no==add.acc_no) printf("Acount Already in use!");
    printf("Name:\n");
    scanf("%s",add.name);
    printf("Age:\a");
    scanf("%lf",&add.age);
    printf("Phone number:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&add.phone);
    printf("Nationality:\n");
    scanf("%s",add.nationality);
    printf("Today's Date *date account created*(dd/mm/yyyy):\n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&add.newa.day,&add.newa.month,&add.newa.year);
    printf("Date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy):\n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&add.dob.day,&add.dob.month,&add.dob.year);
    printf("Account type:\n#Savings \n#Fixed 3 years \n#Fixed 10 years\n");
    scanf("%s",add.acctype);}
//Error starts here
    fprintf(records,"Account Number: %d\n Name:%s\n Age: %lf\n Phone Number: %lf\n Nationality: %s/n Day account created: %d/%d%/%d\n Date of birth: %d/%d/%d %s\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.age,add.phone,add.nationality,add.newa.day,add.newa.month,add.newa.year,add.dob.day,add.dob.month,add.dob.year,add.acctype);
    fclose(records);

    printf("\nAccount created successfully!");
```

So my problem is in the FILE section and using it.

Comment: OT: your program logic is flawed: `f(check.acc_no==add.acc_no) printf("Acount Already in use!");` if the account number is already taken you should not continue asking for the name etc .

Comment: thanks for the comment @Jabberwocky how could i fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `}` in the line

```
   scanf("%s",add.acctype);}
```

This `}` is corresponding to the `{` in `void newacc(){` and terminating the function definition.

Therefore, the call of `fprintf` and line below that is invalid because it is placed outside function bodies.

Move them to correct place (somewhere inside some function body) to resolve the issue.

Comment: oh thanks so much. one curly bracked got me lost for two hours. can you also upvote my post it got downvoted for no reason